# Splitting a date range into weeks

Tags: php, mysql

I'm supposed to a scenario whereby one can be given some amount of money in form of a loan, then select the interest percentage, the duration and the pay back term.

Pay back term options are per week, two-weeks, per month, custom period in days and yearly. When the user clicks submit on the loan form, the php code must do the calculations silently and record to the mysql database.

Possible thing for me to calculate is the loan end date but I also have calculate the periodic dates based on the payment term.

Can anyone guide me, please!

Thank you

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this

Comment: Then what should I do? Look I need a way to monitor the paybacks, given their might be a need for penalty for a late payment. On the same, I have also to generate a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = '2013-01-05 00:00:00'; 
$b = '2013-02-05 00:00:00';
$total_days=ceil((strtotime($b)-strtotime($a))/3600/24); 
$pay_times=0;
switch($type)
{
   case 'per week':
    $pay_times=ceil($total_days/7);
   break;
   case 'two-weeks':
    $pay_times=ceil($total_days/14);
   break;
   case 'per month':
    $pay_times=ceil($total_days/30);
   break;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Where is $type defined?

Comment: Oh actually your code seems to be fine. After looking at it, variable $type is terms right?

Comment: yes, it's used to identity which the user chooses

Comment: Do you have idea how can I derive the exact date of the term? I mean I have 2 pay_times but I want to calculate every date when every pay_time is expiring. Thanks